# Migrating MVC site from local to Azure, having SQL problems

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

So I have been trying to migrate my site from running locally to on Azure, I have been having a lot of problems, I've been stuck on this one specifically for a very long time, hoping someone here can help:

I migrated all my databases to Azure SQL using the Task -> Create Query, then running that Query in the Azure SQL. It changed the structure a bit (now all the tables are in one database, and they all start with "dbo.".

The error I am currently getting when I try to my site is:

"The connection string 'UnitsDBContext' in the application's configuration file does not contain the required providerName attribute."

My Connection Strings:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="UnitsDBContext"
   connectionString="Server=tcp:cbf8vc1b7x.database.windows.net,1433;Database=Database;User ID=username;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    />

    <add name="DefaultConnection"
     connectionString ="Server=tcp:cbf8vc1b7x.database.windows.net,1433;Database=Database;User ID=username;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;"
     providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

The error or a similar one occurs every time I go to a page that uses a database, though other pages load fine. Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Are you by any chance using entity framework database first approach? What did the UnitsDBContext connection string look like when it was running locally? Is the default connection string working?

Comment: I am having this very same problem connection to an MSSQL database running on a virtual machine in Azure. The providerName attribute is present in the app.config of my application, but it still throws this same error. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the thoughts from Ben Narube: -

- You can try logging the connection string to make sure that what is running is actually correct. I have provided a Log4Net example (be sure to remove this afterwards and delete the file because you don't want connection strings lying around):

  ```
  m_log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType );
  foreach( var connectionString in System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings )
  {
      string outString = connectionString.ToString();
      m_log.Debug( outString );
  }
  ```
- Do you have a web.release.config or other config that is replacing this connection string? For example with a xdt:Locator="Match(name)
- Are there any funny characters in your connection string in web.config? Maybe take a look in a hex editor to see if there are.